# Mapping a nested list with the Id of the upper class ASP.NET core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have these two classes:

```
public class QuizDto
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UserToken { get; set; }
        public List<int> AreasId { get; set; }
        public List<QuizQuestionDto> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class Quiz 
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UserToken { get; set; }
        public List<JoinQuizAndArea> AreasOfQuizzes { get; set; }
        public List<QuizQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class JoinQuizAndArea
{
        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        public AreaOfQuiz Area { get; set; }

}
public class AreaOfQuiz
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public List<JoinQuizAndArea> AreasOfQuizzes { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map QuizDto to Quiz, to do so I need to map these two properties:

```
public class QuizDto
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        ...

        public List<int> AreasId { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

to these two properties:

```
public class JoinQuizAndArea
{
        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        ...
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        ....
}
```

Inorder to do so, I created the following Resolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<QuizDto, Quiz, List<JoinQuizAndArea>>
{
    public List<JoinQuizAndArea> Resolve(QuizDto source, Quiz destination, List<JoinQuizAndArea> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var list = new List<JoinQuizAndArea>();
        foreach(var areaId in source.AreasId)
        {
            var joinQuizAndArea = new JoinQuizAndArea();
            joinQuizAndArea.AreaId = areaId;
            joinQuizAndArea.QuizId = source.Id;
            list.Add(joinQuizAndArea);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
interface IValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination,TDestMember>
{
    TDestMember Resolve(TSource source, TDestination destination, TDestMember destMember, ResolutionContext context);
}
```

But when I try to configure the mapping profile:

```
public class QuizProfile:Profile
{
    public QuizProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Quiz, QuizDto>();
        CreateMap<QuizDto, Quiz>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserToken, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserToken))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AreasOfQuizzes, opt=>opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Questions, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Questions));
    }
}
```

I got an error message:

> **CS0311  The type 'QuizzWorld.Mapping.Resolver.CustomResolver' cannot be used as type parameter 'TValueResolver' in the generic type or method 'IMemberConfigurationExpression.MapFrom()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'QuizzWorld.Mapping.Resolver.CustomResolver' to 'AutoMapper.IValueResolver'.   QuizzWorld  C:\Users\Sohaib\source\repos\QuizzWorld\Back End\QuizzWorld Back End\QuizzWorld\Mapping\QuizProfile.cs**

plz, does anyone have an idea what the issue is exactly??
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the compiler error because you have your own definition of `IValueResolver` interface which overrides the one from AutoMapper. Remove your IValueResolver interface or rename it. After that the compilation should succeed.